# What's the policy on "Getting started with <MCUXYZ>" questions?

Tags: discussion

It's hard for me to think of ways to answer [such questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193119/buetooth-4-0-low-energy-help-getting-started) without putting up a shopping list.

I'm not sure why people down-voted the question but up-voted the answer. We surely get those kinds of questions here. Here's a slightly different example: [Synchronous rectification simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194974/synchronous-rectification-simulation). Or [How to get started with Microchip's PIC12 family programming?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196325/how-to-get-started-with-microchips-pic12-family-programming)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is a book, too broad, vote to close.

Comment: Yup, that's inappropriate here.  Vote to close, downvote if you can justify a reason, and move on to something productive.